# Ошибка в python, requests

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://fex24.com/rates.html?sType=json')
print(response.content['rates'])
```

Вылезает ошибка:

```
  File "fex.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(response.content['rates'])
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `response.content` - это ответ в виде байт. К набору байт нельзя обратиться через ключ-строку, как словарю (то что вы пытаетесь сделать в вопросе).
- `response.text` - те же данные, но декодированные из байт в строку (то же самое, что `response.content.decode()`, или `response.content.decode(response.encoding)`, если в `response.encoding` не `None`)
- `response.json()` - если ответ является строкой, содержащей json, то этот метод вернет данные этого json (если нет, то при вызове метода будет ошибка декодирования json). То же самое можно получить с помощью `json.loads(response.text)` (должен быть импортирован модуль `json`).

Вам нужен именно последний вариант, поэтому последнюю строку замените на

```
print(response.json()['rates'])
```